# Unique_ptr: pointer being freed was not allocated when emplaced in list

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have a simple C++ program like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

int main(void) {
  std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>> l;
  int x = 5;
  // throws runtime error: pointer being freed was not allocated
  l.emplace_back(&x);
}
```

When the program is run I obtain the following output:

`a.out(59842,0x7fffb13d1380) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee81489ac: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    59842 abort      ./a.out`

This tells me that during the destruction of the list the unique_ptr object that had been created is being destroyed, and during that destruction the pointer to `x` is being freed when it was never `malloc`ed.

However I would expect that the same would occur in this situation where a `unique_ptr` falls out of scope and is `destroyed`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <memory>

int main(void) {
  int x = 5;

  // does not throw runtime error when falling out of scope and being destructed
  std::unique_ptr<int> p(&x);
}
```

However when the `unique_ptr p` above falls out of scope and is destroyed the program runs fine. Why is the first program giving me an error when destroying the `unique_ptr` but the second one is not? Why does emplacing the `unique_ptr` in a list cause its destruction to fail?

Comment: Both are UB, and may so behave differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happened is that the variable `p` in your second example got just optimized away and thus not resulted in a run-time error.

But the error which occurs is clear, it is trying to free a memory which was allocated on a stack. Note that smart pointers are usually used in conjunction with heap allocated memory, not a memory allocated on a stack.

Comment: You probably can make it work correctly with stack-allocated objects using a no-op deleter...just out of curiosity.

Comment: You are right. Running with -O0 is producing an error. However running with `volatile std::unique_ptr<int> p(&x);` with -O3 still produces no error despite the volatile qualifier which I thought prevents optimizations.

Comment: @RaeesRajwani Making `p` `volatile` does nothing interesting here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought the volatile qualifier would prevent p from being optimized out.

Comment: @RaeesRajwani That is a massive oversimplification of what `volatile` does, and it is probably your whole program that is optimised out because it doesn't do anything. (In the case with the list, this is harder for your compiler to prove so perhaps it doesn't bother.)

Comment: @RaeesRajwani It does but it still doesn't change the fact that he code doesn't have to crash.  Undefined behavior means no error need happen.

Answer (score 3):

Undefined behaviour can result in anything, from a crash, to an apparently successful run, to Britain voting to leave the European Union (whoops, sorry about that, guys… it's amazing what a null pointer dereference can do).

Compilers are *extremely complicated things*. Your program is not a one-to-one mapping of instructions that will be executed by the target computer in sequence; it is a description of roughly how you want the computer to behave. The conversion between the two is highly esoteric and complex. When you go off-piste, you break the language in such a way that the compiler's internal workings — which are constantly making assumptions and taking shortcuts that it knows it's allowed to do, especially when applying so-called "optimisations" — are broken in unpredictable ways.

This is one of them.

In short, if you are *expecting* UB to do anything in particular, you have already failed.

It may be possible, by analysing your compiler's source code and the assembly that came out of your build, to determine exactly why your UB behaved as it did in this case. But this would be a long, arduous and ultimately entirely pointless process.

Just don't make smart pointers out of things you didn't dynamically allocate (or, if you really want to for some reason, provide a custom deleter that won't attempt to `delete` something that wasn't `new`d). Simple!

Answer (score -3):

I've copied your code and compiled it:

```
$ g++ omg.cpp && ./a.exe
Aborted (core dumped)
```

You may try to add another level of indirection:

```
int main(void) {
    int x = 5;
    {
        std::unique_ptr<int> p(&x);
    }
}
```

and see if it helps.

Comment: Sure it does as does my 5.3...what happens when you run the binary?

Comment: I didn't run in because [godbolt](https://godbolt.org) only allows compiling the code but not running it. But even if I ran that, it would throw the same error, as freeing a memory allocated on stack is just a no-no.

Comment: That is not a level of indirection.

Comment: @ProXicT No, you cannot rely on an error/diagnostic here (as shown by the question).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, you are right. What I meant was that freeing a stack memory can result in anything.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thank you, Captain Obvious.

Comment: @bipll If it's so obvious, why did you claim the exact opposite in your answer? And watch your tone.

Comment: Yes, Captain Serious!